# How to check if iframe has completed loading

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Before you answer, I know about the `load` event.

I need to check if an iframe has loaded or not. With images I can do it easy with the [HTMLImageElement.complete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) property, but the iframe doesn't seem to have that... so... does it have something else one can use?

How can you check if an `<iframe>` has completed loading?

---

***Reason:*** I'm currently looping through images in a setInterval loop to check if they all have loaded, and when they have, I fade them in one by one. Looks very nice. And I'd like to add iframes to that fanciness, but can't figure out how to check if the iframes have loaded...

Comment: Do you have control over the content the iframe loads? If so you could send a [PostMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) (on say domready) from that source and use a listener on the parent page

Comment: @PatrickEvans In this case, nope... It's a YouTube player fetched via the `embedHtml` property in a YouTube api response.

Answer (score 1):

If all your use cases are for youtube players than you can use youtube's iframe player api to get onReady events that let you know when the player is ready to be used.

After making sure the [iframe api](https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api) has loaded, `onYoutubePlayerAPIReady()` is called when it is, you can call `YT.Player()` to create or operate on an iframe that links to a youtube video

```
function onPlayerReady(){
   //do work
}
player = new YT.Player('container', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'Video's Youtube Id',
    events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
});
```

The `onReady` property will let the api know which callback to use.

Now you do not have to load/use the iframe api to get these to work. You just have to implement the correct postMessage calls and message event callbacks yourself.

To do this you first have to make sure the url that is being used has `enablejsapi=1` as a parameter. It tells youtube to load the necessary api libraries within the iframe. for instance:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/VgC4b9K-gYU
```

would become

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/VgC4b9K-gYU?enablejsapi=1
```

You then have to send a `listening` and an `addEventListener` postMessage to the iframe's window. This tells the api that there is something wanting to listen to events and which event you are wanting to listen for.

```
var frame = document.querySelector('iframe');

var listenEvent = {"event":"listening","id":1,"channel":"test"};
frame.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(listenEvent),'*');

var listenerEvent = {
  "event":"command",
  "func":"addEventListener",
  "args":["onReady"],
  "id":1,
  "channel":"test"
};
frame.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(listenerEvent),'*');
```

Then you just need to add an `message` event handler to handle any incoming messages.

```
window.addEventListener('message',function(data,origin){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    if(data.event == 'onReady'){
       //do work
    }
});
```

Now if all your cases do not involve youtube players then you may be out of luck, as cross-origin rules do not let you access the dom/events of the iframe content. The source would have to implement something similar to the postMessage / message system like youtube does above.

Demo

```js
window.addEventListener('message', function(event, origin) {
  var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  if (data.event == 'onReady') {
    onReady();
  }
});


function onReady() {
  console.log("Player ready");
}

var frame = null;
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  frame = document.querySelector('iframe');
  var command = {
    "event": "listening",
    "id": 1,
    "channel": "test"
  };

  frame.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(command), '*');

  command = {
    "event": "command",
    "func": "addEventListener",
    "args": ["onReady"],
    "id": 1,
    "channel": "test"
  };
  frame.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(command), '*');
});
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VgC4b9K-gYU?enablejsapi=1"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
<iframe id="my-iframe"></iframe>
<script>
    var iframe_document = document.querySelector('#my-iframe').contentDocument;

    if (iframe_document.readyState !== 'loading') onLoadingCompleted();
    else iframe_document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onLoadingCompleted);

    function onLoadingCompleted(){
        console.log('iFrame loaded!');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `contentDocument` is `null`. Also tried via `contentWindow`, but that gives me a nice *Permission denied to access property "readyState" on cross-origin object* 

Comment: Same with the addEventListener 

Comment: Unfortunately, none would work on the front-end if cross-origin was the issue. I wish I had a better answer. Hope you find a good solution.